# applicationContext, classpath and servlet [appServlet] in context with path

Tags: spring, hibernate, servlets

My application is

[image]
[image]

My applicationContext is as root-context.xml as  is above in WEB_INF/spring/root-context.xml. It is declared in web.xml with the

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

My dispatcher servlet xml is located in WEB-INF/spring/appServlet.servlet-context.xml where I include my

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sat.spring">
    </context:component-scan>   
    <annotation-driven />
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <beans:bean     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

My root-context.xml located in WEB-INF/spring folder is :

```
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->   
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sat.spring">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>    
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>    
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sat.spring.model" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.sat.spring.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="configLocation"> <props > <prop key="hi"></prop> </props> 
            </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="transactionManager"           class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>    
    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor">
    </bean>     
    <bean id="userDao" class="com.sat.spring.daoImpl.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>    
</beans>
```

My login jsp is

```
<body>

 <form:form action="submit" modelAttribute="userForm" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                <td><form:label path="name"> Name </form:label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
                <td><form:label path="id"> password </form:label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
            <td><form:label path="password"> password </form:label></td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" />      </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
```

User keys in name, ID  and password and the login.jsp hits the mvc controller with action =/submit

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveOrUpdateUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user,
            BindingResult result, Model model) {        
        ApplicationContext ac = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml");     
    UserDao dao = (UserDao) ac.getBean("UserDao");      
        Session session;        
        int status = userdao.save(user);    
        System.out.println("----status---" + status);       
        System.out.println("name is: "+user.getName()+ "password is"+user.getPassword());       
        String name = user.getName();
        int id = user.getId();  
        String pw = user.getPassword();     
        model.addAttribute("name", name);   
        model.addAttribute("pw", pw);       
        model.addAttribute("ID", id);       
                return "registered";        
    }
```

my DaoImpl is

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public UserDaoImpl() {
    }
    public UserDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {     
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    @Transactional
    public int save(User user) {        
         Session session;   
        try {           
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();           
         session.saveOrUpdate(user);            
        } catch (HibernateJdbcException e) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }       
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My jdbc.properties file is

```
# MYSQL Driver
jdbc.driverClassName =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.databaseurl =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/uniprojectdb
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
```

and maven dependencies are:
[image]

when I run the application I get to the login.jsp page running on Tomcat 7 with java1.8.
After filling in the fields on login.jsp and after hitting the submit button i get this:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [B:\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.1.RELEASE\WEB-INF\spring\root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: WEB-INF\spring\root-context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified
```

and on console:

```
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\xampp\mysql\bin\;C:\Python34;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\\bin; C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;B:\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.1.RELEASE;;.
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:UniversityProject08' did not find a matching property.
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVCJdbc03' did not find a matching property.
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1491 ms
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:18 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [117] milliseconds.
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(B:\UniversityProject-STS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringMVCJdbc03\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-web-api-7.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:21 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:21 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 14 18:39:21 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/application-config.xml]
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:22 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:22 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 994 ms
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:22 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:22 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 14 18:39:22 EDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:22 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/save],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.save(com.spring.model.Student)
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/option],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.option(com.spring.model.Student,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/registered],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.registered(com.spring.model.Student)
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/viewstudent],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.viewStudent()
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/deleteStudent],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.deletStudent(com.spring.model.Student)
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/studentform],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.showform()
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/deletedStudent],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.dele(com.spring.model.Student)
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/editStudent],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.edit(com.spring.model.Student)
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/edit],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.editStudent(int,com.spring.model.Student,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 1038 ms
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 14 18:39:25 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [jdbc.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
WARN : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2288 ms
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 14 18:39:27 EDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[//],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sat.spring.controller.HomeController.home()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[//home],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sat.spring.controller.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.sat.spring.controller.LoginController.login()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/submit],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sat.spring.controller.LoginController.saveOrUpdateUser(com.sat.spring.model.User,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 14 18:39:27 EDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 14 18:39:27 EDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 620 ms
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10431 ms
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@626daf5e: startup date [Fri Oct 14 18:39:38 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from file [B:\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.1.RELEASE\WEB-INF\spring\root-context.xml]
Oct 14, 2016 6:39:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/spring] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [B:\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.1.RELEASE\WEB-INF\spring\root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: WEB-INF\spring\root-context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)] with root cause
java.io.FileNotFoundException: WEB-INF\spring\root-context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.sat.spring.controller.LoginController.saveOrUpdateUser(LoginController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using mySQL database but nothing is saved/persist there. What I am doing wrong? Please help...Thanks

Comment: where are your maven dependencies ?

Comment: This is Java - please retag to the hibernate tag, instead of nhibernate, since the latter is for .Net.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit the "submit"-button the method `saveOrUpdateUser()` is called. You construct a `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` pointing to "WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml" there. But this location evaluates to "B:\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.1.RELEASE\WEB-INF\spring\root-context.xml" on your system during runtime. Because your app is packaged in a war-file the file root-context.xml cannot be found.

Solution:

There's no need to create a `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`, because a `WebApplicationContext` using root-context.xml is already created (see your log) because of your web.xml. You should use this context and let Spring inject the dependency for `UserDao` (@Autowired).